# UWP video stream bitmaps manipulation

Tags: c#, uwp, video-processing

I coded example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-video-effects

Part of the code:

```
public void ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context)
    {

        using (CanvasBitmap inputBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(canvasDevice, context.InputFrame.Direct3DSurface))
        using (CanvasRenderTarget renderTarget = CanvasRenderTarget.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(canvasDevice, context.OutputFrame.Direct3DSurface))
        using (CanvasDrawingSession ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
        {

            var gaussianBlurEffect = new GaussianBlurEffect
            {
                Source = inputBitmap,
                BlurAmount = (float)BlurAmount,
                Optimization = EffectOptimization.Speed
            };

            ds.DrawImage(gaussianBlurEffect);
        }
    }
```

The problem is: i want to draw points (bitmaps) on frames but i have no idea how to pass specific coord to ProcessFrame function. On input i have x and y coords for every frame where to draw point and on the output i want to have video with added points for every frame.
Thanks for help.[image: Frame before processing]
[image: Frame after processing]

Comment: I think you can manipulate inputBitmap.

Comment: Yes i know. I can draw on it etc. But how to pass coords to that method, to draw point in specific locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
The code below is not suitable solution as the `ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context)` is part of an interface implementation.

My next solution proposal is to create a custom effect, similar to the `GaussianBlusEffect` and many more. An example here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/blob/master/ExampleGallery

~~~
Below the original answer for reference.

You can pass in the X and Y parameters and access the pixels of the image.

```
public void ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context, int X, int Y)
    {

    using (CanvasBitmap inputBitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(canvasDevice, context.InputFrame.Direct3DSurface))
    using (CanvasRenderTarget renderTarget = CanvasRenderTarget.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(canvasDevice, context.OutputFrame.Direct3DSurface))
    using (CanvasDrawingSession ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
    {

        Color[] Pixels = inputBitmap.GetPixelColors();
        // Manipulate the array using X and Y with the Width parameter of the bitmap

        var gaussianBlurEffect = new GaussianBlurEffect
        {
            Source = inputBitmap,
            BlurAmount = (float)BlurAmount,
            Optimization = EffectOptimization.Speed
        };

        ds.DrawImage(gaussianBlurEffect);
    }
}
```

More info: https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBitmap_GetPixelColors.htm

I did not check if the Color[] is a pointer to the live buffer or a copy. If it is a copy, then you have to write back the buffer with SetPixelColors.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that ProcessFrame is a member of IBasicVideoEffect interface so you can't change signature of that function

Comment: This comment is worth adding to the OP.

Comment: I believe your configuration PropertySet can be used here. Create the effect with a property set and keep a reference too it, then change the values in it as you need.

Comment: I think that is the solution. Thanks for help :)